# Get the value of a single recyclerview item when click and send it to dialog box

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to get all the value of a single item on recyclerview and pass it to a dialog. a dialog comes when I click that single item.

Answer (score 0):

Create own callback. Example:

```
public interface OnItemClicked {
     onItemClicked(Item item);
}
```

Your activity or fragment could implement that interface. In implementation you can show a dialog.

Next you need provide a reference of object which implement that interface  first to the adapter ( can be by constructor) and then to the viewHolder ( can be by method in `bindingView()` method)

Then, when you pass a reference to viewHolder. 
You can register views in your viewholder to listen onClickEvent. Your ViewHolder will implement OnClickListener.

Example:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends ViewHolder implements OnClickListener{
       OnItemClicked listener; 
       Item item;

       public void methodWhereYouCreateView(){

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
       }

       public void onClick(View view){
           listener.onItemClicked(item);
       }
}
```

Comment: so how do this interface get the value?

Comment: Hi I added some example above.
You need provide just reference to item to YourViewHolder by bindView and OnItemClicked by constructor. I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this with setTag() and getTag(). Thank you for your answer guys.